# sequence of w3m commands into script for automation

Tags: bash, scripting

i have a specific command sequence in w3m. Now i want to put these commands in a bash script.
Does anyone know how the syntax is for pressing "q", "tab", "enter" etc..?
Thanks in advance,
alessio

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this script?

Comment: Every couple of days sometimes even several times a day I get an automatic generated mail with a link, which I have to confirm by logging in and click a save button. It gets annoying on long term. It runs on a server which has no browser installed, that's on purpose

Comment: I really hope someone has an idea

Comment: I wouldn't do this with W3m commands. Better user curl or python to automate this process. Or look into selenium.

Comment: ah okay, thank you, will try this. for selenium i need a browser which i dont have and wont get. i will try curl. but for the meantime i really want to do this quick with w3m commands until i get the curl/python running

Comment: Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Just use curl to submit the form.

Comment: curl is a good idea sure. but idk the syntax how to get started. i would appreciate if someone has a good link for starters maybe?